# How can I insert a Pandas dataframe into a PostgreSQL table?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am new to Python, I am trying to insert large panda dataframe but somehow I am unable to achieve it.

I tried several approach but getting different exception.

Below is the table structure:

**create table test (column1 varchar(80), column2varchar(300), column3 varchar(80), column4 varchar(80), column5 INT)**

Approach 1:

```
cur = db_conn.cursor() #cursor object
query = "INSERT INTO test (column1 , column2, column3, column4, column5) VALUES (%s,%s,%s, %s,%s,%s)"
dummy_records = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 4,797],['e','f','g','h', 2,343]] #dummy df converted to list
cur.executemany(query, dummy_records)
```

The above code is throwing error as : **not all arguments converted during string formatting**

Approach 2 :

```
engine = create_engine(db_conn)
self.df.to_sql('test', con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

The above code is throwing **'psycopg2.extensions.connection' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'**

Approach 3:

```
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in self.df.to_numpy()]
# Comma-separated dataframe columns
cols = ','.join(list(self.df.columns))
# SQL quert to execute
query = "INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES(%%s,%%s,%%s, %%s,%%s)" % ('test', cols)
cursor = db_conn.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute(query, tuples)
    db_conn.commit()
except Exception as error:
    print("Error: %s" % error)
    db_conn.rollback()
    cursor.close()
```

The above code is throwing error as: **Error: integer out of range**

Error Traceback for Approach 3 :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/kkl/report_automation/test.py", line 10, in <module>
cc165.CC165_rep(conn)
File "C:\Users\kkl\report_automation\report\test2.py", line 73, in __init__
cursor.executemany(query, tuples)
psycopg2.errors.NumericValueOutOfRange: integer out of range
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: The first two lines of "Approach 2" should be sufficient.

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks Gord but Its not working, I have updated the error message which I am getting.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the entire stacktrace.

Comment: For approach 1) Maybe you need to dump your data using json library. Approach 2) which version is your psycopg2 lib? Approach 3) Where exactly does this error traceback come from?

Comment: Thanks all, I am able to insert data now.

Comment: Resolved : 
I had created table COLUMN5 as INT datatype but the 5th column in dataframe is of type string i.e. like '4,564' , '5676' ....